# Sincronização com Team Explorer no VS 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Ao tentar fazer um Sync recebo a mensagem:

> Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your
>   changes before pulling again. See the Output window for details.

Ao tentar fazer um Push recebo a mensagem:

> You cannot push branch master to remote origin because there are new
>   commits in the remote repository’s branch. Pushing this branch would
>   result in a non-fast-forward update on the branch in the remote
>   repository.

O correto seria fazer um merge, certo? Mas recebo a mensagem:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: 1 uncommitted change would be
>   overwritten by merge

Onde resolvo este conflito?

Antecipadmente, agradeço

Diógenes

Answer (score 1):

Pode ter arquivos (novos/alterados) que não estão no seu *commit* (*Untracked files*).

É possível identificá-los pelo ***prompt de comandos do Git***. Navegue até o diretório raiz do projeto/repositório (exemplo *cd c:/Documentos/SeuRepositorio*), digite *"git status"*, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que o arquivo "octocat.txt" não está sendo rastreado (é um *untracked file*).

Se você gostaria de *commitar* os arquivos, adicione-os ao seu *commit*, digite ***"git add ."*** para o Git reastrear todos os arquivos ou ***"git add nomeDoArquivo"***, exemplo ***"git add octocat.txt"***.

Em seguida digite ***git commit -m "Texto do seu commit aqui!"*** para criar um commit.

Caso contrário, descarte-os ([consulte aqui a documentação para maiores detalhes antes de executar os comandos](https://git-scm.com/doc)), você poderia usar ***git reset --hard*** ou ***git reset nomeDoArquivo***. Para desfazer alterações indesejadas você poderia usar ***git checkout -- nomeDoArquivo***.